# How to export and import Android emulator snapshot

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb, android-virtual-device

I didn't find any documentation on how to use these 2 guys
`adb emu avd snapshot pull`
`adb emu avd snapshot push`

I am able to export an existing AVD snapshot with

```
$ adb emu avd snapshot pull baseline /User/user1/baseline  

WARNING: unrecognized file format /User/user1/baseline
OK
```

It seems that I am also able to import the AVD snapshot with

```
$ adb emu avd snapshot push baseline /Users/user1/baseline

WARNING: unrecognized file format /Users/user1/baseline
OK
```

Listing the snapshots with `adb emu avd snapshot list` shows nothing.
What is the correct way to export and import AVD snapshots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Answering my own question

While running `snapshot list` after `snapshot push` doesn't show the *pushed* snapshot, running `snapshot load baseline`  actually loads the *pushed* snapshot and everything works as expected.

#### My course of action

##### Export the snapshot

1. `adb emu avd snapshot save baseline`
2. `adb emu avd snapshot pull baseline /Users/user1/baseline`

##### Import the snapshot

1. Start the emulator (in my case with `-wipe-data`)
2. `adb emu avd snapshot push baseline /Users/user1/baseline`
3. `adb emu avd snapshot load baseline`